# access an object in a function using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am new to JS and have created this original problem from CodeAcademy which works. Now I wanted to put my flock of sheep into an object and access it using my sheepCounter function. I am new to accessing key/values from an object and am stuck on what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
Original Code 

var sheepCounter = function (numSheep, monthNumber, monthsToPrint) {
  for (monthNumber = monthNumber; monthNumber <= monthsToPrint; monthNumber++) {
    numSheep *= 4;
    console.log("There will be " + numSheep + " sheep after " + monthNumber + " month(s)!"); 
  } 
  return numSheep;
}

New Code: 

var flock = {
    sheep: 4, 
    month: 1, 
    totalMonths: 12
};

var sheepCounter = function (counter) {
  for (counter[month] = counter[month]; counter[month] <= counter[totalMonths]; counter[month]++) {
    numSheep *= 4;
    console.log("There will be " + counter[sheep] + " sheep after " + counter[month] + " month(s)!"); 
  } 
  return counter[sheep];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the problem clearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the error in your solution:

```
var sheepCounter = function (counter) {
  for (counter['month'] = counter['month']; counter['month'] <= counter['totalMonths']; counter['month']++) {
    counter['sheep'] *= 4;
    console.log("There will be " + counter['sheep'] + " sheep after " + counter['month'] + " month(s)!"); 
  } 
  return counter['sheep'];
}
```

Comment: However, better to use dot notation here like counter.month, counter.totalMonths, counter.sheep instead of its brackets notation. Choice is yours. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see my rookie mistake :) I owe you a beer! Is there an advantage of using dot notation?

Comment: Looks cleaner, character saving like you put just dot instead of single quotes and brackets :)

Comment: This should help others as I did it with dot notation using a while loop     `var sheepCounter = function (counter) {
 while(counter.month <= counter.totalMonths) {
    counter.sheep *= 4;
   console.log("There will be " + counter.sheep + " sheep after " + counter.month + " months(s)!");
   counter.month++;
  }
};`

Answer (score 0):

You can access your Flock Object like so,

```
alert(flock.sheep); //4
```

If you have an array in an object, like

```
names: ['joe','tom','bob'];
```

You would access that like so,

```
alert(flock.names[0]); // joe
alert(flock.names[2]); // bob
```